# Welche Sojaprodukte werden als Tofublätter bezeichnet?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

Gestern habe ich in einem vietnamesischen Restaurant ein Gericht mit Tofublättern bestellt. Ich weiß, dass Blatt bedeutet, dass es dünn ist. Aber auf English haben wir zwei oder mehr Namen für dünne Tofustücke. "Yuba" und "Bai ye" zum Beispiel.

Ich weiß nicht, welches dünne Sojaprodukt auf Deutsch als "Tofublatt" bezeichnet wird. Werden einfach alle dünnen Sojaprodukte als "Tofublatt" bezeichnet? Oder ist "Tofublatt" eher eine Name, den sich das Restaurant ausgedacht hat?

Welches Sojaprodukt wird als "Tofublatt" bezeichnet?

Comment: "leaf - thin pieces of tofu used for wrapping"?

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic it's not a word I ever encountered. Yet German allows to make up compound words on the spot. so it simply is "leaf of tofu"... nothing specific about it other than what it conveys in terms of the image: a thin piece of tofu of some extent; I recon similar to how I can buy that from algae of ~15x15cm² when making Sushi.

Comment: A quick internet search says *Im Gegensatz zu Tofu sind Tofublätter – auch Baiye Tofu genannt – bei uns bisher weniger bekannt*

Answer (score 3):

Bai ye ist gepresster Tofu, aus dem Tofublätter hergestellt werden.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bai_ye),[2](https://www.soundja.de/produkte/tofublaetter/)</sup>

Yuba wird nicht gepresst, sondern bei der Herstellung wird die Haut abgezogen, die beim Kochen von Sojamilch oben auf der Flüssigkeit entsteht. Was dort entsteht, wird aber auch als Tofublätter bezeichnet.<sup>[3](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuba)</sup>

Blatt wird also nur als Oberbegriff verwendet für beides, da sie wie ein Blatt aussehen. Der Eigenname sagt dann, was es genau ist, dass heißt wie es hergestellt wurde.